# Modify/replace all properties depending on value

Tags: less

Is there a way in LESS to globally replace/modify all properties i stylesheets depending on their values?
I have an online shop skin with dozens of CSS files and references to the values. It would be easier for testing to replace the result values with the right value than to seek for the references (it looks like same value is set in different places).
So something in type of `less.replace(all, '#ff00ff', '#ffffff')` would be nice.

Comment: Sounds like you should start using [LESS variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature).

Comment: Thank you but that's not the point. I have to modify the skin designed by someone else and driven on closed engine where same values are sometimes results of many different lines in LESS/CSS files (some of them are LESS variables). That's not the point. The point is that getting to the right source is painful. I'd rather replace the result values for testing.